# Execute excel formula only for specific cells

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that checks for several things at the same time but I am having trouble with one part of it.

The formula is the following:

=IF(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$17095,N3,$K$2:$K$17095,"<>"&"")>6,
IF((SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND($K$2:$K$49,2)=ROUND(K3,2)))>9),"Always Late / Possible Automation",
IF(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$17088,N3,$K$2:$K$17088,"<3.5")>0,"Delivered Earlier At Least Once",IF(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$17088,N3,$K$2:$K$17088,">3.5")>6,"Always Late","False"))))

The first part checks how many entries in the range having the same value as it is in cell N3 have values different to blank and we want those to be more than 6.
Second part is the tough one, it is supposed to check how many values in the rounded range match the rounded value in cell K3. The issue is the formula checks the whole range and I want to check only for the values which match N3 (in essence like the CountIf works only for that value).

The rest is not so relevant.

Some example data:

![enter image description here][1]

As you see in the end of the table the formula with the rounding works but only because I have limited the data shown to 3 unique values in column N. Even here though if i have a blank it doesnt work becaus ei haven't considered it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No clue if this helps but I have worked a lot with Power BI and DAX and I have done what i want in excel with the following formula in the past:

 IF ( EARLIER ( Users[Country] ) = Users[Country], 1, 0 )


In this case with the example above it would look something like :

 IF ( EARLIER ( N3 ) = N3  ,SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND($K$2:$K$49,2)=ROUND(K3,2)))>9),"Always Late / Possible Automation", 0)

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines @GIK, *albeit* in 'Excel' lingo I imagine this would equate to *=IF(N3:N25=N3, <..>,<..>)* -- unfortunately this returns an array ("True","True",.... etc.) whence so too does the entire equation which will simply be repeated values determined using the initial referenced cell/ranges (if first cell equated to "always late" so too would all other cells in range).. only way around this would be to turn entire equation into array formula which would be tricky / impossible with -sumproduct() component (which cannot be turned into array due to how it operates)

Comment: -- thus one would need to convert everything to array and replace sumproduct.  *However*, we then have IF(range=range,<>...) and that wouldn't work either (always array of 'True's) which would require IF(index(matrix_range,,row())=column_range)..,<>,<>) ? not sure... but anyways, gr8 minds...but then fools never differ either lol:) - give below a go/let me know if you don't come right (accept soln/otherwise as you deem fit for sake of other users -- won't be able to upvote /downvote yet I don't think - until you have larger rep pts. can't remember...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Office 365 compatibility/Excel version, use a bunch of filters.  To avoid an unwieldy formula I've extended ranges to maximum number of rows (customize as required)...

```
=LET(x_,$E$3:$E$25,a_,FILTER($E$3:$E$25,--(x_=E3)),b_,FILTER($B$3:$B$25,--(x_=E3)),IF(SUM(--(a_=E3)*(b_<>""))>6,IF((SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND(b_,2)=ROUND(B3,2)))>9),"Always Late / Possible Automation",IF(SUM(--(a_=E3)*(b_<3.5))>0,"Delivered Earlier At Least Once",IF(SUM(--(a_=E3)*(b_>3.5))>6,"Always Late","False")))))
```

[image: Original vs Revised formula]

*Note: filter does not appear to work too well within countifs for some reason (must be related to syntax RE: arrays vs. criteria TBC).  Thus have replaced `countifs(filter_range,X)` eqn 'types' with `sum(--(filter_range=X))` which works as intended.*

Comment: Hi JB-007 and thanks a lot for the answer and the suggested solution, I just tried it out but it still struggles unfortunatelly with the entries that are different (I have yellowed them out). To give you a view, the idea is that whenever we have more than 9 entries, out of the 12 we have, which are the same for the same company (and no entry is bellow 3.5) i want it to display Always late but possible automation. UNnortunatelly for those two entries that are different also my formula always breaks.

Comment: I added the screenshot in the end of my question because i didnt figure out any other way, sorry...

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but i just want to make clear that the part which i can't still make work is the part of the formula which in the following case:
Company A has 10 entries which are more or less the same and 2 different ones for the last 12 months . The status should have the same for all entries from company A and doesn't change when the KPI is different to the 2 entries which are different.

Comment: So i found this article and formula online and tested it and it seems like at least for the test it seems to assign the correct value to the rows i want (I just had to duplicate one column).

https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequent-text-with-criteria

Comment: no spam don't worry-  have been a little tied up recently so sorry didn't respond sooner - glad you sorted in end. that's main thing!

Comment: @GIK - see previous somment - guesss I was focussing on the part where you say "*issue is the formula checks the whole range and I want to check only for the values which match N3"* -- but doesn't matter know as you've sorted! :) keep well.

Comment: thanks, but i found out that its giving me Delivered Earlier At Least Once also for entries where there's blanks for a specific Mapping key. I tried to edit the formula in the following way (
=LET(x_,$N$2:$N$17026,a_,FILTER($N$2:$N$17026,--(x_=N4)),b_,FILTER($K$2:$K$17026,--(x_=N4)),
IF(SUM(--(a_=N4)*(b_<>""))>6,IF((SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUND(b_,2)=ROUND(K4,2)))>9),"Always Late / Possible Automation",
IF(AND(SUM(--(a_=N4)*(b_<3.5)),(SUM(--(a_=N4)*(b_<>""))))>0,"Delivered Earlier At Least Once",
IF(SUM(--(a_=N4)*(b_>3.5))>6,"Always Late","False")))))


but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem lies here I believe: *AND(SUM(--(a_=E3)*(b_<3.5)),(SUM(--(a_=E3)*(b_<>"")))*.  sum{} will bring back scalar constant (assumes it evaluates w/error), let's say it's 4.  then you have another sum(), let's say this yields 2.  By saying *If(and(5,6) > 0, <then>,<else> is like saying If(FALSE>0,<do if true>,<false>....

Comment: Do me a favour - try again but use this instead of your modification: *=LET(x_,$E$3:$E$25,a_,FILTER($E$3:$E$25,--(x_=E3)*(x_<>"")),b_,FILTER($B$3:$B$25,--(x_=E3)*(x_<>"")),....* then the rest of my equation.  Favour 2: give us some sample data (either as a table tahan can be copied directly in Excel - I mean a simplified 'test case' that has no more than 5-10 rows of unrelated data (e.g. A, B, etc. per my screenshot).  Then we can be walking in 'lock-step' when we try to figgure out what is going wrong